# Maximize database performance for very long digit

Tags: mysql, performance, indexing, hash

I have digitalized image hash, the hash is like 2k integers long.
What's is the best solution to store it in database and search?
Row count will be at least 3millions. Suggestions for performance?
 I'm thinking to create utf8_bin collation column and convert all digits to case sensitive hash and add index on the column,  or is there any other better solution?

P.s. hash can be modified, 1k integers would be less accurate, so i prefer to store 2k or so.

Comment: if you need performance, why MySQL and not some other... MariaDB // Reddis // Percona...etc. etc

Comment: Actually im using mariadb

Comment: Store in database en search ?  What search will you do ? hash is hash, so only option is equals. If so why bother with a 2k hash, just take a smaller hash 64 bit should be ok, then dedup if needed.

Comment: Use some key value databases like mongodb

Comment: Longest hash - accurate image recognition,  i will store more than 3 mil images, so accurancy is important and also i wont store duplicates

Comment: What are you going to search against? The hash value itself?

Comment: the website will have image upload function and such a function should add image if there is no simillar image in the db, so i will compare new hash vs others in the database

Comment: And what do you mean by _best_? By all accounts this should be a pretty small database. You might as well try to build it in a straighforward fashion (one table with one column, and an index on that column) and see if it fits your criteria. On a side-note, IDK if just a hash comparison is good enough. If you're using something like perceptual hashes it might be, but with other things like a LSI an exact match is not what you want, and regular databases aren't good at providing the kind of inexact match you'd need.

Comment: My hash is an improved version of dHash, it resizes image to the 32x32 size and digitalizes all the pixels as exact rgb color values.

Comment: That will may some _similar_ images into the same hash.  Is that OK?  Other, equally similar, pairs will not have the same hash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most compact way to store long is to store as binary bytes using the [VARBINARY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/binary-varbinary.html) data type, not a string with utf8_bin collation. Compute your digital hash of your image, convert to a string of hexadecimal digits, then use [UNHEX()](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_unhex) to convert to binary bytes. Binary bytes store in half the space of the equivalent string of hex digits. For example, a string like `'FFFF'` requires four characters, but `UNHEX('FFFF')` stores in two binary bytes.

Storing more compactly alone is only a modest improvement for performance.
The better performance advantage is to use an index. But InnoDB has a limit on index length. By default the limit is 767 bytes.

If you set `innodb_large_prefix=1` you can increase the InnoDB to 3072 bytes (you must use DYNAMIC or COMPRESSED row format, which means you must use file-per-table). This should be plenty to index the full length of your hashes.

---

Update: I learned that `innodb_large_prefix` is [deprecated](https://dev.mysql.com/worklog/task/?id=7703) in MySQL 5.7.7 and MariaDB 10.2, and the option will be removed in a future release. But don't worry, it's deprecated because the large index support will become default behavior. No more need for the option, because it's effectively always ON.

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
  dhash VARBINARY(3072) NOT NULL,
  UNIQUE KEY (dhash)
);
```

Comment: Good idea, but Is the innodb_large_prefix not deprecated in future mariadb releases?

Comment: I have no idea. I don't use or pay attention to MariaDB.

Comment: Can you recommend hash and index table setup for `mysql  Ver 15.1 Distrib 10.1.24-MariaDB, for Linux (x86_64) using readline 5.1` ?
id+hash columns, but the other parameters?

Answer (score 0):

- MD5 is only 128 bits and can be stored in only 16 bytes in `BINARY(16)`  If you had 9 *trillion* images, there would be only one chance in 9 trillion of a false dup.  For a mere 3 *million* rows, the odds are even smaller.
- Hence, I argue against the need for 2K integers.  (Or did you mean digits?)  There are library routines to take arbitrary strings or files and quickly digest to md5.  (Or sha1 or sha256, etc.)  Don't write your own hashing code.
- Don't use utf8 for any string that is only digits; use `CHARACTER SET ascii COLLATE ascii_bin`.  (But the above `BINARY` is even better; just that it is not practical if you are coming from a string of digits.)
- Don't use `VAR...` if the string or blob is fixed length.
- If you must use digits and live with a 767 limit, then the practical way is to use 2*767 digits and `UNHEX()` and store into BINARY(767).  (Or `VARBINARY(767) if variable length.)
- There are 4 steps for getting to 3072 in pre-5.7.7 versions:  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/limits#767_limit_in_innodb_indexes

Comment: the problem is that, the for example php imagemagick or gd libraries when resizing image to let's say 32x32 size, sometimes creates  an different images but identical rgb values in all the pixels, so is very expensive to collect for example 2-200 md5 hashes for the same visual image, but with identical pixels everywhere. I've decided to make full string with every pixel from of 32x32 and then to do sha256 hash from it, then store this hash to the db.

Comment: It is, I believe, _much_ faster to digest the full image than to resize an image.

Comment: of course faster, but it's not accurate, in my opinion is better to store 1 hash and generate it with more cpu, than to keep few 2-200 hashes in the database as "unique"